# python class doesn't work for different variable

Tags: python

dear expert i am trying to write a simulation and in my code i have a class like this:

```
... (some def are here)

    class multipole:
     global xxp,yyp,zzp,x,y,z,xp,yp,zp,t,tm,h
     xxp,yyp,zzp,x,y,z,xp,yp,zp =xxpyypzzp()  # some initial values calling
     @staticmethod    
     def quad(f1, f2,f3):
       global t,h,mass,ksimax 
       while t < ksimax:
         rk4_two(t,h,mass, f1, f2, f3, xxp, yyp, zzp) # rk function for new xxp, yyp and zzp 
         t = t + h
         tm.append(t)
         xp.append(xxp[1])
         x.append(xxp[0])
         yp.append(yyp[1])
         y.append(yyp[0])
         zp.append(zzp[1])
         z.append(zzp[0])
       return xp, x, yp,y,zp,z,tm
    if __name__ == "__main__":
     qp=multipole()
     quxp, qux, quyp,quy,quzp,quz,qutm=qp.quad(0.,0.,0.)
     hxp, hx, hyp,hy,hzp,hz,htm =qp.quad(0.022,0.,0.)
     oxp, ox, oyp,oy,ozp,oz,otm =qp.quad(-0.023,-0.032,0.0 )
```

my question is this code only calculate (quxp, qux, quyp,quy,quzp,quz,qutm), but not others (others will turn same value of quxp, qux, quyp,quy,quzp,quz,qutm) could you please tell me why? i am new in python any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: this isn't a class.  you never create one, and it has no methods.  also, using `global` inside a class body is highly bizarre.  where did you learn about python classes?

Comment: By *"a class like this"* do you mean a meaningless mess? There's really no point in a class that only has one static method; Python isn't Java! Please provide a minimal example with sensible names, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @Eevee, what do you mean, "never create one"? The class definition is there (ignoring strange design) and an instance is instantiated in the `if __main__ ...` block.

Comment: er, yes, sorry.  but it has no state; it doesn't do anything.  you don't even need that instance since you could call `quad` directly on the class

Comment: Hi Husnu, did you solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Andre, yes i have solve the problem, it was exactly what you said in your answer.  I got another help "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676534/initial-values-for-class-python" because  i didn't understand PEP8 which you suggest to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that this code is... somewhat flawed. I think that the problem is that you are using `t` which is apparently global but you don't reset it anywhere - so this loop:

```
while t < ksimax:
    ...
```

Will only run once, unless you reset `t` somewhere. Some pseudo code to explain why this happens:

```
counter = 0

def do_something():
    global counter
    print "Starting at", counter
    while counter <= 10:
        print counter
        counter += 5
    print "Done"

do_something()
# Starting at 0
# 0
# 5
# 10
# Done

do_something()  # Called again, the counter is at 10 now:
# Starting at 10
# Done
```

As others have mentioned, your code could benefit from some heavy refactoring. Some starting points:

- Naming! What does `xxpyypzzp` even mean? Even if it's obvious to you today, it must be hard to read even for you and unless you have Rainman-like memory you will not understand this next week. Try using descriptive names and if you find yourself adding prefixes or suffixes to variables because you run out of names - think about encapsulating some of this complexity in a class. It seems like the suffixes `xp`, `x`, `yp`, `y`, `zp`, `z` and `tm` are used a lot. At least create a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to hold these values.
- Global variables is generally [considered harmful](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesConsideredHarmful). They make it hard to reason about code - which is why you got this bug in the first place. If you are sprinkling `global` statements over your code there is time to redesign it. Think about which part of your code should "own" which parts of the state.
- Python has a coding standard, called [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - read it and try to follow it.