# initial values for class , python

Tags: python

I have write a simulation code and i would like to insert initial values for my code.

```
some def are here,

class multipole:

    def q(self, f1,f2,f3):
        t=0.
        tm=0.
        xp = idistribution(j,m) # initial xp values it is a list of particles velocities
        while t< k:
           rk(t,m,f1,f2,f3,xp) # calculate new xp value
           xp.append(xxp[1])
        return xp

    def h(self, f1,f2,f3):
        t=0.
        tm=0.
        xp = idistribution(j,m) # initial xp values it is a list of particles velocities
        while t< k:
            rk(t,m,f1,f2,f3,xp) # calculate new xp value
            xp.append(xxp[1])
        return xp
if __name__ == "__main__":
    qp=multipole()
    quxp=qp.q(0.,0.,0.)
    hxp=qp.h(0.052,0.,0.)
```

my question is when i call xp=idist(j,m) it will return random distributed ion velocities but I want to use same distribution  for both class methods (q and h) how can i do this ? thanks in advance. (I am new in python and I am trying to learn it from some web page )

Answer (score 1):

Make it a class attribute and calculate it once:

```
class Multipole:
    xp = idistribution(j,m) 
    def q(self, f1,f2,f3):
        t=0.
        tm=0.
        xp = Multipole.xp[:]
```

If it is a flat list you can make a shallow  copy, if you don't copy any changes to `xp` in your method will be reflected anywhere there is a reference to `Multipole.xp`. If it contains other objects you will need to do a [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in `xp` as an additional parameter to `q` and `h`:

```
class multipole:
  def q(self, f1, f2, f3, xp):
   ....
  def h(self, f1, f2, f3, xp):
   ....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xp = idistribution(j,m) 
    xp1 = xp[:] # copy, so that xp stays untouched
    xp2 = xp[:] # copy, so that xp stays untouched
    qp=multipole()
    quxp=qp.q(0.  , 0., 0., xp1)
    hxp=qp.h(0.052, 0., 0., xp2)

    # xp1 and xp2 now contains your results
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an init method to the class so that each instance will have its own value for `xp` and both methods will use that.

```
class Multipole:
    def __init___(self):
        self.xp = idistribution(j,m)
    #rest of code
```

Then use `xp = self.xp[:]` wherever you need xp.

This will let you have each `Multipole` instance use a different distribution, but calls to both methods on a given instance will use the same distribution.